# Show the content of a Directive when the user clicks a button - almost working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my html page I have a button and a directive snippet like so:

```
<button ng-click="showProfile();"></button>
<profile ng-if="isProfile==true"></profile>
```

In my controller I have initialized the `$scope.isProfile variable = false` and have the function called by the button:

```
$scope.showProfile = function(contact) {
    $scope.contact = contact; // this object needs to get passed to the controller that the directive initiates, but how??
    $scope.isProfile = true;
};
```

In my app I have a directive defined as such...

```
app.directive('profile', function () {
    return {     
     templateUrl: '/contacts/profile',
     restrict: 'ECMA',   
     controller: contactsProfileController,
     link:function(scope, element, attrs) {  
                console.log('k');
     }
   };
 });
```

Everything is working but I can't figure out how to pass the `$scope.contact` object to the controller that the directive references.
 I've tried adding `scope:scope` to the return `{}` of the directive but with no luck. Do I need to do something in the `link` function?  I've spent the entire day reading about directives and am exhausted so any tips would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's what the controller that's being called from the directive looks like as well:

```
var contactsProfileController = function($scope,contact) {
     $scope.init = function() {
        console.log($scope.contact); //this should output the contact value from the showProfile function.
     };
 ....
 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to pass anything, if you are not using an isolated scope the child scope should inherit the contact object.  It does look however like your `showProfile` function takes a contact argument you aren't passing, so when it sets `$scope.contact` it is probably setting it to undefined.  Can you show more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this on your directive.

```
<profile ng-if="isProfile==true" contact="contact"></profile>
```

and add this to the scope

```
app.directive('profile', function () {
    return {     
     templateUrl: '/contacts/profile',
     restrict: 'ECMA',   
     scope: {
          contact: '=contact'
     }
     controller: contactsProfileController,
     link:function(scope, element, attrs) {  
                console.log('k');
     }
   };
 });
```

But I see a couple of issues from your code:
- your showProfile function is expecting a "contact" argument that is not being passed from the button directive, so it will be undefined.
- you are injecting a "contact" dependency on your contactsProfileController controller. Do you have a service / factory declared with that name?

Instead of contact: '@contact', do contact: '=contact'

Comment: It will not work like this. You shall use `'=contact'` (or `'='` for short). `'@'` will read `"contact"` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Since your custom directive is a "component" of sorts, it is a good idea to use an isolate scope and pass the necessary data (i.e. `contact`) via attributes.

E.g.:

```
<button ng-click="showProfile(...)"></button>
<profile contact="contact" ng-if="isProfile"></profile>

$scope.showProfile = function (contact) {
    $scope.contact = contact;
    $scope.isProfile = true;
};

.directive('profile', function () {
    return {     
        restrict: 'ECMA',
        scope: {contact: '='}
        templateUrl: '/contacts/profile',
        controller: contactsProfileController
    };
});
```

Then, the property will be available on the scope (e.g. `contactsProfileController`'s $scope):

```
var contactsProfileController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('contact', function (newValue) {
        // The `contact` has changed, do something...
        console.log($scope.contact);
    });
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your responses were incredibly helpful and I was able to get things working in a matter of minutes after reading your posts.  Thank you so much!!!

Adding contact="contact" into the directive placeholder was key as was adding the scope object to the actual directive code.

So I ended up with:

```
 <profile ng-if="isProfile===true" contact="contact"></profile>
```

and

```
.directive('profile', function () {
    return {     
     templateUrl: '/contacts/profile',
     restrict: 'ECMA',   
     controller: contactsProfileController,
     scope: {contact: '='},
     link:function(scope, element, attrs) {  

     }
   };
 });
```